# Why using this sticky footer doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

Just start to try to make sticky footer but it doesn't work. I'm a new learner, try to use the example but still does not working. I try to change it to fixed but it not being sticky. basicly this is my code

my html and css

```css
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;

html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrap{
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
}

#wrap::after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

footer,#wrap::after{
    height: 80px;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="wrap">
           <header class="main-header></header>
           
           <div class="container"></div>
      </div> <!-- /#wrap -->
      <footer></footer>
</body>
```

can someone help me with this??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
section
{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
.section1
{
 background:red;
}
.section2
{
 background:blue;
}
.section3
{
 background:green;
}
.footer-wrapper
{
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  background-color: black;
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0%;
  left:0%;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1 wrapper"></section>
<section class="section2 wrapper"></section>
<section class="section3 wrapper"></section>
<footer class="footer-wrapper">
  <h1>Footer Text</h1>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

You had some typos. You missed to close `class` property. Change this in `HTML`

```
<header class="main-header></header>
```

switch it to

```
<header class="main-header"></header>
```

...and in your `css` you forgot to close class `container`

```
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
```

change to

```
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
}
```

This is your code corrected. I've added the text "TEST" to the footer to make it visible.

```css
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
}

html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrap{
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
}

#wrap::after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

footer,#wrap::after{
    height: 80px;

}
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="wrap">
      <header class="main-header"></header>
      <div class="container">
      </div>
   </div> <!-- /#wrap -->
   <footer>TEST</footer>
</body>
```